# railsアプリでcapistrano deployしても変更内容が反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

railsアプリをawsで作成しています。capistranoでdeployできるようにしたのですが
コードを変更しても変更内容が反映されません。unicorn nginxを使っています。
awsサーバ側に入ってコードを確認すると変更されています。

config/unicorn/production.rbはこんな感じ

```
  $worker  = 2
  $timeout = 30
  $app_dir = "/var/www/hoge/current"
  $listen  = File.expand_path 'tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock', $app_dir
  $pid     = File.expand_path 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', $app_dir
  $std_log = File.expand_path 'log/unicorn.log', $app_dir

  worker_processes  $worker
  working_directory $app_dir
  stderr_path $std_log
  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid

  preload_app true

  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end
  after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

Comment: capistoro ではなく、 capistrano です。

Comment: 失礼しました。修正しました。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log/unicorn.logに以下ログが出ていました。


   `` /home/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:31:in `build': /var/www/hoge/releases/20161017131031/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound) ``


20161017131031ディレクトリが無かったのでコピーして作ったら動くようになりました。
なぜないディレクトリが指定されてたのかはわかりませんが(^^;;

Answer (score 1):

1. 各種変数をログに出力して想定した値になっているか確認する
2. before_fork 内に適当なデバッグ文を挿入して、処理がどこに分岐しているか確認する
3. 例外を握りつぶしている箇所があるため、適当なメッセージが出力されるように修正する